# How to call my React component properly? No webpack errors and no dom

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, handsontable

***(UPDATE:) I refactored App.js and made the two changes in comments. Here is the newest code, still not rendering on the dom.***

My basic React app won't render and I'm hoping I can get a little help. I'm utilizing this https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/installation/

Here are code snippets:

app.js in src folder:

```
import './App.css';
import Handsontable from 'handsontable';
import 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css';

const container = document.querySelector('#example');
const hot = new Handsontable(container, {
  data: [
    ['', 'Tesla', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Ford'],
    ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ],
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  height: 'auto',
  licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation' // for non-commercial use only
});

function App() {
 return <Handsontable hot={hot} />;
}

export default App;
```

index.js in src folder:

```
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

index.html in public folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <!--<div id="example"></div> --> <!--I added this because the source docs here told me to add a tag, but I'm confused https://handsontable.com/docs/javascript-data-grid/installation/-->
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

If I get this figured out, I can write out the exact path everything is being called and I can understand how it flows.

Can anyone help me? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Typo?  The `App()` function component doesn't *return* anything.

Comment: @David thank you, I fixed that. I also made another change based on the source code for the sample from Handsontable. I'll post that now.

Comment: For your `container` you might be able to use a `ref` but I think you should checkout the [React handsontable version](https://handsontable.com/docs/react-data-grid/installation/)

Comment: @RubenSmn thank you I'm going over that now! I really appreciate your observations and advice!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to apply your React components to the an element with id of `root`

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
```

But in your `index.html` you have no element with the id of `root`. You can add this after your `noscript`

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Like mentioned in the comments your `App` does not return anything.

```js
function App() {
  return <Handsontable hot={hot} />;
}
```

Comment: Okay I made all those changes. I really appreciate it. I'm going to post what I have now, Including one other change. It is still not working. @RubenSmn

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that got it working. Thank you so much you two. @David and @RubenSmn. Here is the final code that worked:

App.js

```
import './App.css';
//import Handsontable from 'handsontable/base';
import 'handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.min.css';
import { registerAllModules } from 'handsontable/registry';
import { HotTable } from '@handsontable/react';

registerAllModules();

export const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const data = [
    ['', 'Tesla', 'Volvo', 'Toyota', 'Ford'],
    ['2019', 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ['2020', 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ['2021', 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ];

  return (
      <HotTable
        data={data}
        rowHeaders={true}
        colHeaders={true}
        height="auto"
        licenseKey="non-commercial-and-evaluation" // for non-commercial use only
      />
  );
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Thank you!! We've got DOM.
[image: DOM rendered!]